# "one of the things which is ..." or "one of the things which are ..."?

Tags: grammar, subject-verb-agreement

The question is simple: Which sentence is correct?

> This is one of the things which **is** really important to her.

or

> This is one of the things which **are** really important to her.

When I think about it, the second sentence seems correct because 'things' and 'are' are both plural and so in agreement. But, I may unconsciously use the first one when I'm writing, say, a letter to a friend. Is my unconscious mind really wrong here?!

Comment: This is a member of a group of **things** (plural) which **are** important.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences can be correct:

> This is **one** of the things which **is** really important to her.

This is one thing. It is really important to her.

> This is one of **the things** which **are** really important to her.

Out of all of the things that are really important to her, this is one.

So, either **one** thing **is** important, or **the things are** important. In the singular meaning, the other things might or might not be really important to her.

Another difference is that

> This is one of **the things** which **are** really important to her.

needs no previous referent because "things" is general enough to be understood generically, whereas

> This is **one** of the things which **is** really important to her.

needs a referent for "things" because "one" makes it specific:

> There are many interesting things in her life, some important, some not. This is **one** of the things which **is** really important to her.

Adding a comma makes the meaning clearer:

> This is **one** of the things, which **is** really important to her.

Comment: Doesn't the sentence need to be either: "This is one of the things, **which** is really important to her." or "This is one of the things **that** are really important to her." ("which" requires a comma, no comma requires "that")?

Comment: @fixer1234 No, there's nothing that **requires** either "which" or "that". It's your preference. Some users will use only one, some will use only the other, some will use either at different times.